# How do I rename column names that have Parenthesis and Quotes?

Tags: python, pandas

I have 2 dataframes, A and B. I use some commands in A to get a pivot_table (and I used aggfunc to get total of 'Duration' data). After this, I merge A and B. When I run a command to show columns name, columns from A look strange, with parenthesis and quotes, like showed below:
Index([            ('Name', ''),
       ('Code', ''), ('sum', 'Duration'),
                         'Position'],
      dtype='object')

Header example:

```html
<table border="1">
<tr>
  <td>('Name', '')</td>
  <td>('Code', '')</td>
  <td>('Sum', 'Duration')</td>
  <td>Position</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

As you can see, only Position (which is from dataframe B). I tried to use rename function to change those 3 columns from A, but it didn't work.

What I expected to have as final was:

```html
<table border="1">
<tr>
  <td>Name</td>
  <td>Code</td>
  <td>Duration</td>
  <td>Position</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Does anybody know what kind of syntax I should use to rename those columns? Actually I save the file as csv and then I need to change the column names manually.

Comment: Why is HTML being mixed into this? At best I could say you have a _multiindex_ but I don't get the HTML table

Comment: It would be more beneficial to see the code that generated this to fix that, rather than put bandaids on top of bad code.

Comment: Sorry, guys...the HTML was the only way I found to add a table, I should have mentioned that. I spend more time trying to add a table in other ways than to really explain that.

Comment: @QueilaMartins if my answer solves your problem, then kindly accept it. Or provide some feedback!

Comment: Sorry I still didn't accept it, @QusaiAlothman. I'm not sure if it will work as I tested something similar with Rename method previously. But I'll test it today (I was in a hurry delivering something else and I had to leave this for some days, but I'll come back to it as I need to solve it too). Thanks and sorry for the delay!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `df.rename(columns=your_column_mapping)`, like this:

```
df.rename(columns={"('Name', '')" : "Name",
                   "('Code', '')" : "Code",
                   "('Sum', 'Duration')" : "Duration"})
```

However, just like the others told you in the comments, you really should investigate how these weird names were generated in the first place.

Documentation of the rename method can be found [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html).